# Entity Framework NuGet package not source-controlled/in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I mapped my solution (using Entity Framework) onto a new PC. The solution reports a compile error because the EntityFramework.dll can't be found. Digging deeper it seems that TFS only stores the packages/repositories.config file in source control. I'm unable to re-add the Entity Framework as VS2012 reports it as already installed (green tick).

What's the normal process to fix this? Is this a wider issue with source-control and NuGet packages? Should I just add the DLL to source control?

FYI, the `HintPath` is for the project is: ..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll which of course doesn't exist.

My current workaround is to hack the 'packages.config' to delete the EF item and then go back into the NuGet dialog.

Comment: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click your solution you should have the option to "Enable NuGet Package Restore" - this should sort your issue out.

You may also need to right click your solution and got to "manage nuget packages etc..." - it may give you an option to restore missing packages.